# Duplicate form inputs into new bootstrap tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently dealing with a form submission page, where a user can submit expenses for each trip they make during client hours. I've got the form all setup, pulling info from the database for the select input fields I have and I'm currently holding it within a Bootstrap card (for aesthetics, idk).

My problem is this: I want to be able to duplicate this form, but with its default values, into a bootstrap tab upon clicking "New Expense." I have the new expense tab link working to dynamically add and remove tabs, but I want the form and its default values to be visible upon clicking "New Expense."

```
$(".nav-tabs").on("click", "a", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!$(this).hasClass('addNew')) {
        $(this).tab('show');
    }
})
.on("click", "span", function () {
    var anchor = $(this).siblings('a');
    $(anchor.attr('href')).remove();
    $(this).parent().remove();
    $(".nav-tabs li").children('a').first().click();
});

$('.addNew').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(".nav-tabs").children().length; //think about it ;)
    var tabId = 'expense_' + id;
    $(this).closest('li').before('<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#expense_' + id + '">New Expense</a><span>x</span></li>');
    $('.tab-content').append('<div class="tab-pane" id="' + tabId + '">Expense Form: New Expense ' + id + '</div>');
   $('.nav-tabs li:nth-child(' + id + ') a').click();
});
```

Here's a JSFiddle of what I currently have: [Bootstrap Dynamic Form Tabs](https://jsfiddle.net/anjurp72/)

My main problem with adding my form's code to my JS file is the sheer length of the code and what's included in it. Is there anyway I can achieve what I'm trying to achieve  without hardcoding the HTML elements in my JS file?

**EDIT** I've just noticed that upon creating the tab with the "Add Expense" link, it doesn't actually save said tab whatsoever. I need this to stick in case a user loses connection/their phone dies, the tab will still be there upon returning.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here we can first copy the default form created earlier. Then, when each new one is created, we can transfer it. I think that's what you want.

```
var defaultValues = $('#expense_1>.card-body').html()

$('.addNew').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(".nav-tabs").children().length; //think about it ;)
    var tabId = 'expense_' + id;
    $(this).closest('li').before('<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#expense_' + id + '">New Expense</a><span>x</span></li>');
    $('.tab-content').append('<div class="tab-pane" id="' + tabId + '"><div class="card-header">Expense '+ id +'</div><div class="card-body">'+ defaultValues +'</div></div>');
   $('.nav-tabs li:nth-child(' + id + ') a').click();
});
```

Comment: This is perfect, it's exactly what I needed. Thank you so much!

Comment: one more question: do you know how I'd sort the tab out so the <span>x</span> is actually in the tab, rather than on a new line? if I put it within the <a> tag ($(this).closest('li')...), then I delete a tab just created, and create a new one, it will auto-increment rather than revert back to the number after the previous tab i.e. deleting #2 then adding new will become #3 rather than #2

Comment: Actually have a simple management. place the closing icon in the tags "a". And then run two "parent" functions instead of one in the deleted part of the page. `$(this).parent().parent().remove();`. So that he can erase the right thing.